# Как называется "->" после объявления функции в Python и для это нужно?

Tags: python

Как называется "->" после объявления функции в Python и для это нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Это типизация. Нужна для автотестов и для автодополнения в среде разработки

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что это больше как аннотация для читающего код, которая никак не влияет на функционал? Т.Е. это не аналог int main() {
  myFunction(); 
  return 0;
} в C++, где перед функцией объявляется возвращаемый тип?

Comment: На исполнение не влияет.

Comment: Как в тайпскрипте)

Comment: Спасибо..........